# Can someone explain what the xml:base attribute is used for in XHTML5?

Tags: xml, html

I was wondering what does the xml:base attribute do and what are it's values in XHTML5. and does the xml:base attribute have any restrictions?

Comment: on a side note what's with all the unicorn avatar's? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Documentation for the `xml:base` can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/#syntax). It allows a redefinition of the base address used by relative addresses in child elements.

This is the example for that source,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc xml:base="http://example.org/today/"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <head>
    <title>Virtual Library</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <paragraph>See <link xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="new.xml">what's
      new</link>!</paragraph>
    <paragraph>Check out the hot picks of the day!</paragraph>
    <olist xml:base="/hotpicks/">
      <item>
        <link xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="pick1.xml">Hot Pick #1</link>
      </item>
      <item>
        <link xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="pick2.xml">Hot Pick #2</link>
      </item>
      <item>
        <link xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="pick3.xml">Hot Pick #3</link>
      </item>
    </olist>
  </body>
</doc>
```

In this case the "What's new" link points to `http://example.org/today/new.xml`, which is the `doc` element's `xml:base` absolute address plus the `xlink:href` attribute's relative address.

The `olist` element's `xml:base` address redefines the base address, using the domain of `doc`'s `xml:base` but changing the path. So the subsequent links are relative to `http://example.org/hotpicks/`.