# How to change the baseURI of a Node in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI) claims that there are two ways of changing a *Node* `.baseURI` attribute:

- When an HTML `<base>` tag is found in the document; (1)
- When this is a new document created dynamically. (2)

They don't provide an explanation as to **how** it can be done dynamically (2). They also state that you **shouldn't** add `<base>` elements in html documents (1).

How can I change the `.baseURI` attribute dynamically in Javacsript?

**[EDIT]** According to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204795/can-someone-explain-what-the-xmlbase-attribute-is-used-for-in-xhtml5) using `base` is perfectly legit. Why is MDN advising against it then?

Comment: I think this begs the question: why do you need to? `.baseURI` is read-only for a reason; perhaps there's a better way. What are you using it for? If you need to, wouldn't having a global variable set to your base URL be more appropriate?

Comment: @Cory, I'm adding import tags to the DOM head dynamically. Global variables are of no use here, unfortunately.

Comment: The edited link to the other SO question is related to XHTML5 – a standard that never came to living as far as I know. It seems totally unrelated to reality. This question remains unanswered. **Re: Why is this needed?** Open a new window and create dynamic content into it, which will use images and everything just like it would within the parent document. This needs the parent document's baseURI also applied to the new document.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the .baseURI attribute is read only. 
Check here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljhvjgiu.php